# $skip and $limit not returning results after first page

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a relatively simple schema and aggregate system to lookup data for user's outfits, sort them by the number of Likes, Dislikes, or Favorites (each is a collection of user IDs in an array), and then return the data in pages of 12 results at a time. The first page correctly returns 12 objects, but the second page returns none. I have 16 items total that are eligible to be returned (4 should be returned on the 2nd page). Here is my schema:

```
outfitSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    Items: [{AccessoryType:String,AssetId:mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed,IsLayered:Boolean,Puffiness:Number,Order:Number}],
    Name: String,
    Description: String,
    Category: String,
    Created_At: Number,
    Creator: Number,
    Likes: [Number],
    Dislikes: [Number],
    Favorites: [Number]
})
```

And my aggregate query is as follows:

```
let true_skip = limit*pageNum
let true_limit = true_skip+limit

query = mongoose.model("Outfit").aggregate([
  { $match: { Category : cat}},
  {
    $addFields: {
      sortLength: {
        $size: "$"+sort
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      sortLength: sortBy
    }
  },
  { $project: {"_id":1}},
  { $skip: true_skip},
  { $limit: limit}
])
```

`limit` is always 12 and `pageNum` iterates up from 0. It may be worth noting that I execute the query at a later point with `data = await query`. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Where does sort come in this expression? `$size: "$"+sort` ?  And can you add sample documents and the desired result? even better you can create a playground at https://mongoplayground.net and share the link in the question.

Comment: `sort` is defined as either "Likes", "Dislikes", or "Favorites" based on which array's count I want to sort the results by.

Comment: How are you getting total number of pages?

Comment: I’m not at the moment. I’m just returning results in chunks of 12 until nothing more returns or less than 12 items return. Then I know it’s the last page.

Comment: The issue is in your code, you need to debug it step by step just using a console.log, the issue is in one of the logic in pagination and its variables, it should return 4 documents on the second page if the value of `true_skip = 12` and `limit = 12` and same values in `sort` and `sortBy` variables that were in the first page.

Comment: Correct, that should be occurring. I wouldn’t be here if I hadn’t already tried debugging and logging all variables. Everything checks out the way it should be, but there are no results returning after the first 12. I expanded the limit to other numbers, and they returned correctly as well, but the second page was still empty.

Comment: The query looks good, but we can't debug this code, might be there some issues in a variable declaration or in part of the code that is not added in question.

Comment: @Collin can you show the code how pageNum is iterating? can you manually enter pageNum=1 and see what you are getting

Comment: @Collin A bit offtopic but you should add _id as second criteria to the sort order to get stable results. See [sort-consistency](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/#sort-consistency)
The only other idea is that `cat` might be empty on the second call, which I'm hesitating to ask because you said you've checked.

Comment: I think your `pageNum` iteration is causing this issue. Since it's starting from 0, for page 2 it should be 1. But I believe it's more than that. That's why your skip value is greater than 12, maybe 24 and above and hence no output is returned.

Comment: Are you sure the `sort` field is never null?

Maybe try to change the expression `$size: "$"+sort` by `$size: { $ifNull: [ '$'+sort, [] ] }`
This would normally throw an error, but who knows.

Comment: I believe we're missing information here - if `true_skip` and `limit` really are set to 12 (on page 2), your `sort` doesn't change, and there really are 16 query results, then I don't see anything wrong with this.